# Can't find package.json with custom cra-template

Tags: reactjs, templates, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I've created my cra custom template https://github.com/iBobo5/cra-template-ld.git and I'm trying to create a new app using this template with this command line:

```
yarn create react-app test-app --template https://github.com/iBobo5/cra-template-ld.git
```

During installation process this error blocks all:

```
Cannot find module 'https://github.com/iBobo5/cra-template-ld.git/package.json'
```

But you can easily see the package.json file exists.

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Per https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates it seems only templates published on NPM or downloaded locally are supported, not links straight to git repos.

Comment: Then please write an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved: you can use github repo with this command:

```
npx create-react-app [app-name] --template git+[github template url]
```

Comment: working with this tweak